# Copy cell from a coloumn if value is starting with #excel #formula

Tags: excel

looking for some help...

the below is an example excel table. i have tried to work with alternatives... but none work for me... so again i came back to excel :(

**i need :** i am looking for a formula or a way to do the below job

i want to copy the cell starting with `0` in `B` to `A`

**MY TABLE**

```
      A           B            C        D         E
1               0568695
2               956568
3               54649845
4               09447895
5               45649845
6               789454
7               546465465
8               0965445  
9               456465465
10              454478
```

**I NEED**

```
      A           B            C        D         E
1   0568695     0568695
2               956568
3               54649845
4   09447895    09447895
5               45649845
6               789454
7               546465465
8   0965445     0965445  
9               456465465
10              454478
```

UPDATE :

is it possible to copy the value in `A` till next Empty cell

```
      A           B            C        D         E
1   0568695     0568695
2   0568695     956568
3   0568695     54649845
4   09447895    09447895
5   09447895    45649845
6   09447895    789454
7   09447895    546465465
8   0965445     0965445  
9   0965445     456465465
10  0965445    454478
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="0",B2,A1)
```

And drag the formula down to the bottom.

Note: You will have to evaluate A1 manually.

Comment: @user2704822 You put the value that should go in A1 manually. In this case, you copy B1 and paste in A1. ^^ But after this, just fill the formula to the bottom.

Comment: how to write it as  `0` or `1` ...

Comment: =IF(LEFT(B2,1)="0 OR 1",B2,A1) - didn't work for me :(

Comment: @user2704822 `=IF(OR(LEFT(B2,1)="0",LEFT(B2,1)="1"),B2,A1)`

Comment: @user2704822 refresh the page to get the proper formula since I did an edit. You're welcome :)

Comment: is the correct - =IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,1)="0",LEFT(A1,1)="1")AND(RIGHT(C1,1)=""),PERFECT,"")

i'm trying to do if B1 is 1 or 0 AND C1 is NULL then PERFECT else EMPTY...

Comment: @user2704822 The `AND` works quite similarly to `OR`, like this: `=IF(AND(OR(RIGHT(A1,1)="0",LEFT(A1,1)="1"),RIGHT(C1,1)=""),"PERFECT","")` Also, you need to quote `PERFECT` :)

Comment: Worked :D thanks a ton :D #ThatsAllForDay :) love your support thanks a lot again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(LEFT(B1, 1)="0",B1,"")
```

Hope this helps,
kpark.